# Email table - consolidate To and Group under one Subject row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Given:
subject, To, Group
----------------------
subject1, name1, -1
subject2, name1, -1
subject2, name2, -1
subject2, 0, group1


Desired format:
Subject, To
-----------------
subject1, name1
subject2, name1, name2, group1
```

So this is an email table and I'm trying to condense rows like the **Desired format:** below. Is there an easy way to collapse the To/Group into same subject line?

A little more info: don't need fields where `Group = -1` and `To = 0`

Comment: @rod little bit when you posted i'm in sleep continental timing differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basing on your sample data we can get this using XML path()

```
declare @t table(subject varchar(10),too varchar(10),groups varchar(10))
insert into @t (subject,too,groups)values
 ('subject1', 'name1', '-1'),
('subject2', 'name1', '-1'),
('subject2', 'name2', '-1'),
('subject2', '0', 'group1')

;with CTE AS (
select subject,STUFF((select distinct +','+too from @t 
    where subject = t.subject 
        for xml path('')),1,1,'')+
STUFF((select distinct +','+groups from @t
     where subject = t.subject 
        for xml path('')),1,1,'')R from @t t
GROUP BY subject )
select subject,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',R) > 0 
    THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(R, CHARINDEX(',', R) + 1, 20),'-1','')
         ELSE replace(R,'-1','') END [To] from CTE
```